# Netmiko SCPConn Socket is closed exception

Tags: python, pycharm, netmiko

I'm always getting a netmiko exception: "Socket is closed"
Here is the code:

```
    # ---- Connect to the device
session = ConnectHandler(device_type=device_type, ip=device['ipaddr'],
                         username=creds[0], password=creds[1])

net_connect = session

#transferring file to device

net_connect.config_mode ( )
net_connect.send_command ( 'ip scp server enable' )
scp_conn = SCPConn ( net_connect )
s_file = file_s
d_file = file_s
scp_conn.scp_transfer_file ( s_file , d_file )
```

After executing the command scp_conn.scp_transfer_file ( s_file , d_file ) I get the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Which Netmiko `device_type` are you using?

Is there some reason you are not using the Netmiko already built-in secure copy? [I am assuming here there is an existing secure copy driver].